# AutoLayout how to keep the child view at the bottom of parent view if the height of parent view changes

Tags: ios, swift

I have a parent view initially it has height of 250, at the bottom of that view i have a label which has bottom and left constraints i want to keep this label always at the bottom of this blue view always but when in code i change the height of blue view, label does not stick to bottom of view

[image: Image View Controller]

I am changing the height with the following code

```
greyView.frame.size.height = greyView.frame.size.height + 200;
```

how to keep the label at the bottom of blue view, even the height of blue view  changes???

i have tried to re adding the label bottom constant value but it does not go to bottom

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: UIButton) {

    greyView.frame.size.height = greyView.frame.size.height + 200;

    bottomMargin.constant = 0;

}
```

I have added following constraints to the label

[image: Label contraints]

I dont have any problem in the storyboard if i change the height of blue view in storyboard label comes to bottom but when i change the height from code label does not come to bottom

it shows like this..
[image]

Comment: Create outlets for your constraints and change them, so that both of them stick together.

Comment: @harsh can you explain bit more how to change the constraints, should i have to add all the constraints again when i change the height like label bottom and right constraint

Comment: You should call `updateConstraintsIfNeeded()` after updating the values of your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set these constraints:

[image]

Right and bottom anchored to the parent and weight and height is up to you, the important thing is bottom and right.

*You can ignore my values since it's just an example*

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you can do this. I don't recommend changing the height of the label view programatically. Set the height constraint to the button >= to the amount it currently is when it's first drawn. 
That way when you change the height of the blue view, it will expand. What other constraints do you have on the button?

You issue right now is that the constraints for the button are keeping the view that specific size.

Edit #1
so I misunderstood your question. I tried it myself and didn't have enough time to come up with a good solution using constraints. I disabled constraints and just use autoresizing mask and setting it to the bottom and it was moving (see screenshot). Constraints are doing something tricky here. Ill try to get you a better solution when I get home. 
[Autoresizing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SvYZ.png)

Comment: With your updated screenshots.. you are settings bottom constraint to superview in the label. Set it to the button. Or set vertical spacing to button to 0.

Comment: i don't want to align the label to the bottom of button i want to align it to the bottom of blue view , i have only placed button to change the height of blue view.